# Access VBA Receiving an Error on OpenRecordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Dim recvar
Dim addrvar
Dim grpvar
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim db As dao.Database
Dim findExisting

recVar = Forms!locspecificinfofrm.ActiveDataSubfrm!Record_ID.Value
grpVar = Forms!locspecificinfofrm.Location!Grp_ID.Value

findExisting = "SELECT [Addr_ID] FROM [Prov_Address_Bridge] WHERE 
[Record_ID] = " & recVar & " AND [Grp_ID] = " & grpVar & " AND [Addr_Type] = 'Remit'"

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(findExisting)
```

I'm receiving the following error:

> Runtime Error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set

Initially I thought it was treating my last line like this:

```
set rst = nothing
```

But the variables that I'm using to test the query should pull *something*, I just keep getting this error. The strange thing is I use this same snippet of code in other events on the same form and it works fine.

Comment: So I feel silly. I omitted the following line: `set db = currentDb` - It works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set db

```
Set db = CurrentDb
```

Comment: Yeah I noticed that within a minute of posting. Ugh...thank you!

Comment: Do you know a fix for this? I'm getting a 'No Current Record' error if my RecordSet returns nothing. I wasn't aware that this was an invalid value.

Comment: you probably found it by now. Try this If rst.EOF Then MsgBox "null"  or If Not rst.RecordCount > 0

Answer (score 0):

Pelase, specify the line which raises the error. I'm assuming that the error is in the line with code:

```
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(findExisting)
```

As I see, in your code you are not set an instance to `db` like this:

```
Set db = CurrentDb
```

or, for example

```
Set db = wrkAcc.OpenDatabase("YourDatabase")
```

Use your debug yo see if the variable db is not in `Nothing`. If it is you must set in `db` variable the correcto instance of `dao.Database`.